# Chrome failed to start with Selenium script running from Docker entrypoint

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to set a docker image that runs Robot Selenium scripts automatically after its creation but the following exception is occurring everytime:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

I'm using the selenium/standalone-chrome image as a basis and I can run the scripts myself when I interact with the environment through bash, which is really bugging me.

I tried the following arguments:

```
add_argument('--no-sandbox');
add_argument("--disable-extensions");
add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
add_argument("--no-sandbox");
add_argument("--disable-gpu")
```

But nothing changed.

And also tried using different methods to call robot at the dockerfile.

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "${TESTWARE}/run.sh" ]
CMD [ "robot","-d ${OUTPUT} ${TESTS}"]
ENTRYPOINT robot -d ${OUTPUT} ${TESTS}/aaa.robot
```

So in summary, the scripts work, I can run then in my personal environment and in the docker image when I access it directly and call the scripts through bash. But when I try to set the docker image to run then automatically it fails with the exception above.

Anyone has a clue on what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you seen this: [WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50642308/3124333) Do any of the ideas there help?

Comment: @SiKing, nope, nothing changed from my side unfortunately.